# How should I translate 细心 here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I have this sentence:

这些发明都要归功于他在实践中留心观察，细心发现。

I think 留心，细心 and 用心 all have much the same meaning of 'careful, attentive'. I understand 留心观察 as 'carefully observe', but I don't like 细心发现 as 'carefully discover'. How can you 'carefully discover'? That makes no sense in English.

How should I interpret 细心 here?

Comment: How about meticulous(ly)?

Comment: Would you really write 'meticulously discover'? "I meticulously/earnestly/seriously discovered Radiation." I think not. Maybe it means 'by means of this careful observation discover'. Chinese often leaves out more than it says. @songyuanmao: I know of no word 'aborative' what does that mean?

Answer (score 4):

`细心` means `认真` (`earnestly`, `seriously`) more than `小心` (`carefully`) here.

And `留心` (and `用心`) here means more to `pay attention to` or to be `not absent minded`.